# When saving images from the pictureBox after 180 images i'm getting exception Parameter is not valid what could make it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
int counter = 0;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;
            using (Bitmap bmp =
              new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height))
            {
                pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
                bmp.Save(@"e:\screenshots\" + "screenshot" + counter.ToString("D6") + ".png"
                         , System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            }
            if (counter == 1200)
                timer1.Stop();
        }
```

I can see the first 180 images on the hard disk.
But then it show the exception.

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DrawToBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle targetBounds)
       at Youtube_Manager.Elgato_Video_Capture.timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\Elgato_Video_Capture.cs:line 191
  InnerException:
```

Not sure why it throw the exception after 180 images and not before.

Line 191 is:

```
pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
```

Comment: Why do you create a new bitmap in every timer tick? One is enough.

Comment: The timer set to 100ms but also same exception on 1000ms. I create a new bitmap each time since i want to save each time a new image from the pictureBox1 since the image in the pictureBox1 is change all the time it's not the same.

Comment: Again, as I said. You don't need to create a new bitmap in every tick. Create the bitmap **once**, eg when the form loads or when you start the timer, your choice. In the timer tick event you need only `pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap`, `bmp.Save`...